# error in storing data to mysql however echo gives correct output

Tags: php, mysql

in my tableX some datas are there which looks like this

```
<h1>ghhhhhh!</h1>
http://twitter.com/USERNAME
<h1></h1>
       http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhikN8s5lI/AAAAAAAABL0/3Pbb3EAeo0k/s1600/Srishti+Rai1.html
<h1></h1>
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhiXGx1RII/AAAAAAAABLc/XNp_y51apks/s1600/anus7.html
<h1></h1>
http://cyz.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhh1ILX47I/AAAAAAAABKk/gX-OKEXtLFs/s1600/4r-2.html
<h1></h1>
http://cyz.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhiHGgb-KI/AAAAAAAABK8/zEv_41YzMhY/s1600/19+(1).html
<h1></h1>
http://cyz.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhihkpZZKI/AAAAAAAABLs/zDnlZkerBd8/s1600/Pooja+Gurung.html
```

when i echo the same php code it gives correct output but when i am storing these details in mysql only one row is getting stored in mysql row.
my code is this

```
<?php 

include('connect.php'); 



 $idmg=$_POST["id"];
 $res =mysql_query("select * from tablea");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(sus== '0'){ 

  $output=''.$row['content'].''; 


 echo $output;//this output gives the above result but when i store in db it stores first row


mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tablea (content) VALUES ('$output')");


}    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the SQL you're generating?

Comment: ?? What is `sql_fetch_array()`? Is that supposed to be `mysql_fetch_array()`? If so, you have only called it once and therefore only gotten the first row.

Comment: And `sus == '0'` is not valid PHP unless `sus` is a defined constant (I kind of doubt)

Comment: You have an extra "(" right here: if((sus== '0'){

Comment: @Michael everything is right then only echo is giving correct result but when i am inserting those details to mysql it stores only first paragraph.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @burmat that is typographical error. everything is right then only echo is giveing correct result

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty strings here? `$output=''.$row['content'].'';`

Comment: @andrewsi please help i tried the output directly in mysql and its storing full data but when i use through browser it stores only first line.completely fedup .please help. echo is giving full output and the same string $output i am trying to store in mysql but it saves only one line please help

Comment: @DCoder please help i tried the output directly in mysql and its storing full data but when i use through browser it stores only first line.completely fedup .please help. echo is giving full output and the same string $output i am trying to store in mysql but it saves only one line please help

Comment: @user1515503 - could you please add the output to the question?

Comment: @andrewsi http://twitter.com/USERNAMEhttp://3.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhikN8s5lI/AAAAAAAABL0/3Pbb3EAeo0k/s1600/Srishti+Rai1.jpghttp://4.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhiXGx1RII/AAAAAAAABLc/XNp_y51apks/s1600/anus7.jpghttp://2.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhh1ILX47I/AAAAAAAABKk/gX-OKEXtLFs/s1600/4r-2.jpghttp://2.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhiHGgb-KI/AAAAAAAABK8/zEv_41YzMhY/s1600/19+(1).jpghttp://2.bp.blogspot.com/_fqPQy3jcOwE/TJhihkpZZKI/AAAAAAAABLs/zDnlZkerBd8/s1600/Pooja+Gurung.jpg

Comment: @andrewsi mysql stores only first link/line of output

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you have sql_fetch_array() and not [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)  ?

You also need to iterate through your results if you want more than one row.

```
<?php  
include('connect.php');   
$idmg =$_POST["id"]; 
$res  =mysql_query("select * from tablea"); 
$row  = sql_fetch_array($res)
  if($sus== '0'){  
   $output=mysql_real_escape_string($row['content']); 
   echo $output;
   mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tablea (content) VALUES ('$output')");  
}
?>
```

And as @DCoder said, you should be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/pdo), the code you have now is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: its one row content only .one row content is what i have given in top.if it was wrong then echo will not give correct op correct???/ but echo is giving 100% correct op but while storing the result in mysql only one line is getting stored however my datatype is text

Comment: sorry its mysql instead of sql

Comment: Are you sanitizing your data before inserting it? If the web page you are scraping contains a single ' then it will break the SQL statement. You should use something like mysql_real_escape_string() - see updated answer.

Comment: The above code escapes the output before echoing. You should see in the echo some extra "\" that were not previously there, Correct?

Comment: Using `mysql_real_escape_string` is putting a bandage on a wound that will eventually kill you. +1 for PDO!

Comment: @tadman  please help i tried the output directly in mysql and its storing full data but when i use through browser it stores only first line.completely fedup .please help. echo is giving full output and the same string $output i am trying to store in mysql but it saves only one line please help

Comment: @DavidHoude  please help i tried the output directly in mysql and its storing full data but when i use through browser it stores only first line.completely fedup .please help. echo is giving full output and the same string $output i am trying to store in mysql but it saves only one line please help

Comment: Sorry man, I think everyone here has answered to the best of our ability. I suggest reading our answers and implementing them *cough* PDO *cough*, and post your new code if you continue to have issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert is failing because you have unescaped data in `$output`.  Take DCoder's advice above and use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: please tell where i have done mistake . echo is giving correct output are correct but mysql is storing only first line

Comment: See David's comment above.  You need to sanitize your data.

Comment: +1 - the query looks fine when you echo it, because your browser doesn't process the data, just display it. MySQL is trying to interpret your data, and a ' or " or ; or \ will break your query.

Comment: Unescaped data means special characters are conflicting with the data (in this case '$output') being sent and received to the database and they need to be properly escaped with a "\" before them (or stripped out completely).  One method (although your should look into PDO) can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @awm please help i tried the output directly in mysql and its storing full data but when i use through browser it stores only first line.completely fedup .please help. echo is giving full output and the same string $output i am trying to store in mysql but it saves only one line please help

Answer (score 1):

Your code some-what corrected:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php'); 

    $idmg=$_POST["id"];
    $res = mysql_query("select * from tablea");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($sus== '0'){  // what is sus? If variable.. should be $sus
        $output = $row['content']; // .'' is literally nothing.. 
        echo $output;

        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tablea (content) VALUES ('$output')");
    }
?>
```

What I think you are trying to do:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php'); 

    $idmg = $_POST["id"]; // not actually used
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tablea');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $output = $row['content'];
        echo $output;
        // do anything else you want.. in your case ?enter the data back in?
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablea(content) VALUES('$output')");
    }
?>
```

What you should be using:

```
<?php
    $idmg = $_POST['id']; // <-- not actually used
    $res = $mysqli_connection->query('SELECT * FROM tablea');
    while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $output = mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['content']);
        echo $output;
        // Do whatever else you like
        $mysqli_connection->query("INSERT INTO tablea(content) VALUES('$output')");
    }
    $res->free();
    $mysqli_connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: This answer is uses `mysql_query` which is like juggling chainsaws. It will eventually cause considerable pain.

Comment: @tadman true, but I am trying to get OP a feel for what is going on.

Comment: What's going on is this code should be thrown into the incinerator and replaced with something using the supported interfaces. I know you're just trying to help, though, but answers like this only make `mysql_query` stick around longer.

Comment: @tadman Okay I understand it is using a depreciating method to provide an outcome, but I was merely translating what he provided into something that worked. He was going about it a certain method and was just trying to guide him to get his code into a correct syntax. I will append to my answer with some code that hopefully is worthy of not being 'incinerated' by your belief.

Comment: I like to think Stack Overflow is here to provide not just answers, but good answers. Ironically you've appended a use of `mysqli` while still ignoring the escaping. Don't use string interpolation.